# SSRS 2012, push permission changes down the structure?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs

I want to make a permission change for someone at the top level of SQL Server Reporting Service and have it trickle down to each folder and report, this is automatic if that folder/report is set to inherit but if it is set to override then it does not. We have hundreds of reports that this 1 permission has to be changed for and I don' want to revert customer permissions on the reports. How can I push this permission change to all the folders and reports?

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867850/ssrs-revert-to-parent-security)

Comment: @ShooterMcGavin Thanks but I don't want to revert to partent permissions as that will override the custom permissions of all the reports. I need to figure out a way to push a single change from parent to all children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matthew, 
Given that you do not want to revert to parent security on your sub-folders and children reports, I think your only option will be to write some custom code which accesses the SSRS Web Services API.  I've done something similar using powershell for one project and a C# script task from SSIS for a different project and should work well although it won't be accessible from the SSRS management portal.

I'm 99% certain that there is no functionality within SSRS that will directly handle your request out of the box.

Comment: I am not against writing some custom code. When you where doing yours did you run across any good documentation you would recommend me checking out?

Comment: Sure; Here's a good tutorial from the standpoint of creating a standalone C# app to communicate with the Web Services API. 
[link](http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/lesson-12-using-ssrs-web-services.html)
Here's another one on managing SSRS reports from Web Services using powershell.  [link](https://blogs.infosupport.com/managing-ssrs-reports-with-powershell/)